# Block debugger to step into functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++

**I'm searching for a way to block the Visual Studio debugger to step into certain classes and functions when pressing F11. Or block some files so the IDE won't open them, just step trough (except when there's an exception).**

I know this sounds kind of stupid, but I'm using smart pointers and other helper classes, many overloaded operators, simple expression are composed of many function calls, which disappear on optimization, so it's not a speed issue, but it is a debugging issue, opening and closing that many files all the time, going through many functions, accidentally leaving the target code and so on.

Here's an example, of what I'm talking about:

```
stepToThisFunction(objectOfIgnoreClass->ignoreFunction());
```

When the debugger is on this line, pressing F11 should enter only `stepToThisFunction`, stepping through the `ignoreFunction()` or possibly any function call from `objectOfIgnoreClass`.

Some native equivalent of the managed `DebuggerStepThrough`. I don't want to use CLI. Just a keyword or macro written before the function/class. I also found something, some registry key modifications, but that doesn't seem to be the thing I'm looking for, or I don't understand it's mechanism (I don't even understand what registry keys have to do with this). Also, "put a breakpoint" and "run to cursor" are not accepted solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a macro to do precisely this.  It's not very fast, but it's very useful (in fact I've also converted it to C# so I can use it in an AddIn, which is much faster).  Just customise the regexp with the functions you want to ignore and bind to F11 or another key of your choice:

```
 Sub StepIntoNextRealFunction()
    DTE.Debugger.StepInto(True)
    Dim frame As EnvDTE.StackFrame = DTE.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame
    Dim fn As String = frame.FunctionName
    Dim skipRE As Regex = New Regex("operator.*->|MyString::MyString|operator new|operator.*\*|ignoreFunction")
    If (skipRE.Match(fn).Success) Then

        DTE.Debugger.StepOut(True)
        DTE.Debugger.StepInto(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit: here's a C# version - you'll need to create an addin and then wire up to the DTE object:

```
  public void StepIntoNextRealFunction(DTE2 dte)
    {
        Debugger2 debugger=(Debugger2)dte.Debugger;
        debugger.StepInto(true);
        while (true) {
            EnvDTE.StackFrame frame = debugger.CurrentStackFrame;
            string fn = frame.FunctionName;
            Regex skipRE = new Regex("operator.*->|basic_string.*basic_string");

            if ((skipRE.Match(fn).Success)) {
                debugger.StepOut(true);
                debugger.StepInto(true);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SinistraD: Open the Macro Explorer, create a new module if you haven't created one already and paste the function in there, then in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard you can map a keyboard shortcut.  Take a look at some of the sample macros provided too -- there's some really useful stuff in there.

Comment: Meanwhile found it in MSDN (removed my comment, haven't seen your reply). I'll have to rewrite this to C#, because I don't have VB.NET installed. Do you have a C# version (as you mentioned in your post, or were you trying to say .NET)? Not a problem if not. I speak C#, so I think I'll manage.

Comment: I've got a version in C# -- added above

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the line and choose "Step into specific". Then choose the function you want.

Comment: This truly works, but it's not intuitive, you have to do this every time, isn't there a bit more permanent solution? Like a macro or something

Answer (score 3):

There is an unsupported feature in Visual Studio that allows you to permanently configure the debugger not to step into certain functions.  The details are given in this MSDN blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx